# Single column not being updated in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am tying to update a single column of a table messages and I have the following code:

```
public function messageSeen(Request $request){
    $data = Message::find($request->id);
    $success = Message::where('id', $request->id)->update(array('is_seen' => 1));
    if($success){
        return response()->json(['status'=>'success'], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['status'=>'Data not updated'], 404);
    }
}
```

I am getting the response Data not updated. If you question, does the column **is_seen** exists? then yes it does. Even I tried fetching the data having id `$request->id`, it gives the proper data. I wonder why is the data not being updated? Am I doing right thing to update column or is there an way out to update column in different way?

I tried the other way like the following:

```
public function messageSeen(Request $request){
    $id = $request->id;
    $result = Message::find($id);
    dd($result->message);
    $data = array();
    $data['is_seen'] = 1;
    $data['message'] = $result->message;
    $data['user_id'] = $result->user_id;
    $data['conversation_id'] = $result->conversation_id;
    $this->messages->fill($data);
    $success = $this->messages->save();
    if($success){
        return response()->json(['status'=>'success'], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['status'=>'Data not updated'], 404);
    }
}
```

But here I am getting unexpected thing with this method. Here I am being able to do dd($result) and being able to get data like this:

```
#attributes: array:9 [
    "id" => 22
    "message" => "How are you?\r\n"
    "is_seen" => 0
    "deleted_from_sender" => 0
    "deleted_from_receiver" => 0
    "user_id" => 2
    "conversation_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2019-09-29 03:42:39"
    "updated_at" => "2019-09-29 03:42:39"
  ]
```

however, if I tried to do `dd($result->message)` then I get null! What am I doing wrong?

I tried the following code:

```
public function messageSeen(Request $request){
    $id = $request->id;
    $result = Message::find($id);
    $data = array();
    $data['is_seen'] = 1;
    $data['message'] = $result[0]['message'];
    $data['user_id'] = $result[0]['user_id'];
    $data['conversation_id'] = $result[0]['conversation_id'];
    $this->messages->fill($data);
    $success = $this->messages->save();
    if($success){
        return response()->json(['status'=>'success'], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['status'=>'Data not updated'], 404);
    }
}
```

and it worked but instead of updating it is adding new column when the message is seen. But first I don't understand why do I have to do $result[0]['key'] in the first place.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "getting unexpected thing"? What kind of "thing is that"? And for the next example, how could an update query add a new column?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which fields in your table can be [mass assigned](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment), by adding or updating the `$fillable` property of your model:

```
protected $fillable = [..., 'is_seen', 'message', ...];
```

This is required for the `create()` and `update()` methods, as those accept "mass" variables in the array you pass in.  Whereas with `save()` you have to manually, explicitly, assign the properties on the model, so there is no risk of accidentally saving something you didn't mean to.  And this is exactly the behaviour you are seeing - `update()` is not working, but `save()` is.

Answer (score 0):

**You should try this**

```
public function messageSeen(Request $request) {
        $input = Request::all();

        $data = Message::find($input['id']);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $update = array();
            $update['is_seen'] = 1;
            $success = Message::where('id', $input['id'])->update($update);

            if ($success) {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'success'], 200);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Something went wrong'], 400);
            }
        } else {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'Data not updated'], 404);
        }
 }
```

- Value depends on data type of `is_seen` are string or integer

Comment: This may be the answer, but adding an explanation would greatly increase the quality of your answer.  What did you do, and why do you think it will help? *Explain* your answer, so future visitors of all skill levels can learn from it.  [Code-only answers are considered low quality on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers).